WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError unity

I got a security issue from google when uploading my app,
and I found a solution from this thread.
But in my case, I'm developing my android app in Unity Engine, so I doubt that solution will work for me.
Will commenting out onReceivedSslError solve my issue? Or is there a better solution for this?


Ok but the error you're having is absolutely nothing to do with unity - and not unityscript.. that died years ago.
